# Changing My Phone Number Help

Tags: iphone

I want to change my cellphone number but I am not sure if that will erase the entire contents of my iPhone. Will it?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all ! If your change your SIM card (which may not always be necessary if you change your number) , it may erase data on the SIM card, but usually there is nothing on it except some factory useless numbers. But all the data on your phone should be safe and sound.

Comment: Sometimes changing the number does not even need a SIM card chnage